# I am getting file tree in my localhost

Tags: php, xampp

I have downloaded the entire site from the remote server c panel and uploaded it into a local server (xampp/htdocs).

When I open this in my browser I can only see the file tree:

[image]

How do I fix this?

I want to run my website on a local server.

Please help me.

Comment: you just need to specify the file in the link so when you click on any folder or the files listed you can also check the url changes as well. This is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

So in order to change the default web directory you need to change the **httpd.conf** (should be located in apache/conf/httpd.conf)
Look for **DocumentRoot** and change the value for the Directory.

Also once you are at it you might want do disable directory listings unless you really need it.
In the httpd.conf look for someting like:

```
Options Includes Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

and remove the Indexes, so it loks something like:

```
Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Once you are done, save the changes and don't forget to restart Apache.